# What is best tool/approach to develop with Bootstrap so that mobile sites work optimally on every device?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

We are developing a part of our website to be accessed on **mobile devices**.

We only want to develop **one site for both web and mobile**, not have a separate mobile site to maintain.

We are using **Bootstrap 3**.

**1. How can we best understand how our website is going to look on various devices?**

Here we have used the Chrome and Firefox tools to show the website on the iphone i.e. 375 x 667 but the two views look completely different:

[image]

- Is there a tool that shows one exactly how a website will look and react on all major devices?
- Also, the zoom on a mobile device doesn't actually restack the navbar but simply zooms in on the navbar so you don't get the effect that you get when you resize your browser.

We have looked at a number of news sites, and some seem to allow zooming larger and others don't allow zooming at all:

- http://news.google.com - cannot zoom at all
- http://spiegel.de - cannot zoom at all
- http://newsweek.com - can zoom larger but not smaller
- http://abcnews.com - cannot zoom at all
- http://zeit.de - can zoom larger but not smaller

So there seems to be a lack of standards here.

**2. What is the best strategy to develop websites with Bootstrap so that they will be optimally usable on every device?**

Answer (score 1):

I use Mobile/RWD Tester for Google Chorme and Firefox [LINK](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/)

I've spent years working with these 2 are not "100% accurate" have their pixels of difference but if they are the most reliable at least for my taste.

Minimize your browser screen I can tell an idea but Apple android, change much. The only reliable is that if minimizing your browser, you have horizontal scroll is that the mobile also going to have. Acuerdate a default browser zoom is usually "high" with which mobile can really look bad and have it perfect! : D

regards from Spain!!!

Comment: Yes, your link seems to go to the Web Developer plugin which I used to make the screenshot on the right above. But these two tools are showing completely different ways of how the website will apparently appear on a specific mobile device. Is there not some tool which shows this accurately?

Comment: exact exact nothing, if you see google chrome and firefox desktop are the same but very different in some respects, one pixel up one down ... imagine how that would be in mobile mode !! Depends on the browser, the truth that this point is very poorly worked by developers but each OS is a world ... I work more with firefox is more accurate than Google Chrome, this usually fail enough. I wish I could help more and better :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use smartphone emulators instead of the built-in browser stuff.
The Best of course is, if you have different devices that you can maybe borrow from your friends...